# Is it possible to implement IPv6 on a virtual interface (eth0:1 interface) in Linux?

Tags: linux, network-interface, ipv6, virtual-interface

If I assign an IPV6 address to the virtual interface created like `eth0:1`, then it gets automatically assigned to its real interface `eth0`.

It's all working fine on IPv4, but I need IPv6 on the virtual interface as well. I tried everything that worked on the physical interface and I cannot get anything IPv6 to show for the `eth0:1` interface.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:9f:02:81:97  
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fc00:1234:1::10/120 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fc00:1234:1::70/120 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fc00:1234:1::42/120 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fc00:1234:1::40/120 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::204:9fff:fe02:8197/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:5528 (5.3 KiB)
          Base address:0xe000 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:9f:02:81:97  
          inet addr:192.168.1.40  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Base address:0xe000
```

Comment: What's you use case? If you just want two IPv6 addresses on the `eth0` interface (my guess based on that `eth0` and `eth0:1` have the same MAC address above), just add another address on `eth0`. If you are using some kind of automatic address configuration (SLAAC or DHCPv6), please note that the addresses provided by these are based on the MAC address.

Comment: This style of interface alias is deprecated anyway, and you should no longer be using it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IPv4 implementations originally only supported one address per interface, which is why virtual interfaces were invented so you can add multiple addresses on the same physical interface.

IPv6 supports multiple addresses per interface by default so there is no need to use virtual interfaces for IPv6. Just add them to the interface itself, the end result is the same.